# How to turn floats into integers (inplace) in a pandas.Series and ignore nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series `col1` (from a column of a dataframe) with float values (only 1.0 and 0.0) and nan values, e.g.

```
0      NaN
1      0.0
2      1.0
3      NaN
4      1.0
5      0.0
```

I would like to replace (in this Pandas series) all floats with integers. So goal is to have this as a final output:

```
0      NaN
1      0
2      1
3      NaN
4      1
5      0
```

With all my approaches so far, I get at some point the warning "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" when trying to replace values inline. E.g. with this approach:

```
finder = col1.notnull() #to get "True" for all non-NaN values
ind = col1[finder].index
for i in ind:
   col1[i] = col1[i].astype(int)
```

What would be the best way to do this? Would creating a new pandas Series and use it as a column replacement in the dataframe better? How could I do this?

Comment: convert the series to `astype('Int64')`: try `s = s.astype('Int64')` where `s` is the variable for the series. If you want to update the DataFrame then `df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype('Int64')`

Comment: I doubt you will be able to: "ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"

Comment: The solution by @It_is_Chris works.